# Flutter - Slow gradle build

Tags: performance, android-studio, flutter, gradle, visual-studio-code

I have recently started Flutter development and on my machine, and the gradle build seemingly takes forever when completely restarting the app or running it for the first time, at times it gets quite frustrating. I am using an Ubuntu 20.04 (KDE Plasma env) with 8 GB RAM/ 240 GB SSD and using VS Code for running the app. Is there any way to optimize this? Would appreciate any suggestion on the same. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/optimize-your-build#configure-the-jvm-garbage-collector) documentation by developer.android.com there is a way to optimize gradle build by using JVM Garbage collector.
Add this parameter to your `gradle.properties` in your android folder you can find it on `/{your-project}/android/`:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX:+UseParallelGC
```

and if there are already value set in this field, just add a new option:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m -XX:+UseParallelGC
```

Comment: what does it mean by  > and if there are already value set in this field, just add a new option: my file has `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true` then what I should change or add?

Comment: and when i add those 
`org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX:+UseParallelGC`
`org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m -XX:+UseParallelGC`
lines its being more slowly to build.

Comment: you already have the lines above, so you should go with second approach. There is only one line of `org.gradle.jvmargs`